# Not able to get the layout output of json return after calling GET method from REST api

Tags: c#, android, .net, rest, xamarin

i have been following this article http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1029 and trying to extract json from REST api for to show a list in android after someone clicking button, my json look like

```
[{"id":"1","name":"test","address":"test","country":"usa"},{"id":"2","name":"test1","address":"test1","country":"uk"}]
```

This are my codes
class file of HackerNewsRepository.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Shared
{

    public class HackerNewsRepository
    {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Entry>> TopEntriesAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/api/v1/info");

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entry>(result);
        }
    }

    public class Entry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Names { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }


    }

}
```

class file of App.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Shared;

namespace DNC.NewsReader
{
public class HackerNewsPage : ContentPage
{
    private ListView listView;
    public HackerNewsPage()
    {
        Title = "Hacker News Stories";

        listView = new ListView
        {
            RowHeight = 80
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { listView }
        };
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var entries = await new HackerNewsRepository().TopEntriesAsync();
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(HackerNewsEntryCell));
        listView.ItemsSource = entries;
    }
}
public class HackerNewsEntryCell : ViewCell
{
    public HackerNewsEntryCell()

    {
        var id = new Label();
        id.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Id");

        var name = new Label();
        name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

        var grapes = new Label();
        grapes.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Address");

        var country = new Label();
        country.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Country");




        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {Id, Name, Address, Country}
        };
    }

}
public class App
{
    public static INavigation Navigation { get; private set; }
    public static Xamarin.Forms.Page GetMainPage()
    {
        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new HackerNewsPage());
        Navigation = navigationPage.Navigation;

        return navigationPage;
    }
}
}
```

This is main activity class file

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
...
namespace DNC.NewsReader.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "DNC.NewsReader", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

SetPage(App.GetMainPage());
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is there in `deserializeObject` part and Also i applied different logic example given in net but could not, please help me to give the output in android from given json format. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should :

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Entry>>(result);
```

if needed, try using small case on `Entry` class attribute so it would same with the JSON string.

Comment: Thank you @andrefadila, i get the output but not exactly what want it does not show 'name' and 'country', give output only of 'id' and 'address'. I tried to pull up all and show out in list, can you tell me what's wrong there why it's not showing all?

Comment: You are using "Name" in your class and "names" in the json.